# Firefox Addon with toolbar, access object from browser.xul

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, toolbar

I am developing a Firefox addon which will be primarily a toolbar but will have some dialog/windows for things like preferences.

In `browser.xul` I declare my global variable which I will store all variables within:

```
var coolAddon = {};
```

Then in my toolbar I want to be able to call methods of `coolAddon`, for example on button clicks.

If I open a dialog from `browser.xul`, in the dialog I can access `coolAddon` using `window.opener.coolAddon`, which works well. The problem is this does not work on the toolbar - only on windows/dialogs. What happens in the toolbar is `window.opener` is `null/undefined`.

How can I access `coolAddon` that is declared in `browser.xul`, from within the toolbar? I don't want to redeclare it because I need to keep it's current property values (I realise my example does not currently have any properties or methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access coolAddon directly from your toolbar. It is in the browser context.

Window.opener is only needed when you are in a completely different window.